# Fix Text widget size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made an application and part of it involves entering a question and answer. I have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x250")

#Main question/answer frame
createFrm = tk.Frame(root)
createFrm.pack(expand = True) #To centre the contents in the window


#Create question entry area
cnqFrm = tk.Frame(createFrm)
cnqFrm.pack()
cnqFrm.pack_propagate(False)

#Question entry
cnqLabQ = tk.Label(cnqFrm, text = "Question")
cnqLabQ.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
#Frame for question Text
cnqTxtQFrm = tk.Frame(cnqFrm, height = 100, width = 100)
cnqTxtQFrm.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
cnqTxtQFrm.grid_propagate(False)
#Question Text
cnqTxtQ = tk.Text(cnqTxtQFrm)
cnqTxtQ.pack()
cnqTxtQ.pack_propagate(False)

#Answer entry
cnqLabA = tk.Label(cnqFrm, text = "Answer")
cnqLabA.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
#Frame for answer text
cnqTxtAFrm = tk.Frame(cnqFrm, height = 100, width = 100)
cnqTxtAFrm.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
cnqTxtAFrm.grid_propagate(False)
#Answer Text
cnqTxtA = tk.Text(cnqTxtAFrm)
cnqTxtA.pack()
cnqTxtA.pack_propagate(False)
```

Despite the fact the Text widget is in a Frame with `grid_propagate(False)` and a fixed height and width, and the Text widget itself has `pack_propagate(False)`, it still expands to far larger than it should be. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give the text widget an explicit size, so it defaults to 40x80 average-sized characters. The most common way to force it to a specific size that is determined by its parent is to give it a size that is smaller than the containing widget, and then let `grid` or `pack` expand it to fit the space given to it. So, start by giving the text widget a width and height of 1 (one).

Next, in this specific case you are calling `grid_propagate(False)` on the containing frame, but you are using `pack` to manage the window. You should call `pack_propagate` if you're using `pack`. You also need to tell pack to expand the text widget to fill its frame.

Finally, there's no point in calling `cnqTxtQ.pack_propagate(False)` since that only affects children of the text widget and you've given it no children.

---

All of that being said, I strongly encourage you to not use `grid_propagate(False)` and `pack_propagate(False)`. Tkinter is really good at arranging widgets. Instead of trying to force the text widget to a specific pixel size, set the text widget to the desired size in lines and characters, and let tkinter intelligently arrange everything else to line up with them.

Comment: I tried this and it just made the Text widgets 1 wide by 1 tall, not 100 by 100. I tried changing the background of the parent frame and giving it a border just to see if the Text widget was filling it or not, and the border went around the Text widget. For some reason the parent frame is the same size as the Text widget, even though the parent Frame has a fixed width. Why is this?

Comment: Did you do everything I said, including `cnqTxtQFrm.grid_propagate(False)`, `cnqTxtA.pack()`? Tkinter is very deterministic. If you give the container a width and height, turn off _pack_ propagation in that container, and the properly `pack` a widget, it absolutely _will_ work as described.

Comment: I changed the `grid_propagate(False)` on both Frames to `pack_propagate` and didn't give the Text widgets a specified size and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: This worked great for me. In order for this to work correctly you need to give weight to the column and/or row that the scrolled text/text widget is on with a sticky of NSEW. This will correctly allow this to grow (at least for the grid system)